# How to modify the argument of the GroupBy() method?

Tags: c#, linq

This is my a linq query that filter tasks by range name then group them by language.

```
var transTasks = taskData
                .Where(t => t.RangeName == rName)
                .GroupBy(t => t.CultureID)
                .Select(g => new { language = g.Key, tasks = g });
```

Now I'd like to use the same query for a different grouping. Instead of grouping by CultureID, I'd like to group by TaskOrder.

So I've create variables like this

```
Func<QuoteTaskInfo, bool> predicate = null

if(tasktype == "translation")
{
   groupPredicate = t => t.CultureID;
{
else
{
   groupPredicate = t => t.TaskOrder;
}
```

I'm getting the following error: `"Cannot convert expression ... because some return type are not convertible to the delegate return type".`

Any help on how to write a delegate that would return a `bool`?

The same goes with `Select()`. If the criteria is task order, then the `key` for the select should be `TaskOrder` instead of language.

Thanks for helping

Comment: Why is your delegate returning a `bool` in the first place?  The parameter to a `GroupBy` is not a *predicate* -- it's intended to designate a *key*, which is of whatever type that your property is.

Comment: Don't understand : a group by doesn't take a "predicate", it takes a "property", which MAY be a boolean, but MUST not. Did you try to change your func type to `Func<QuoteTaskInfo, object>` (if CultureID and TaskOrder are not of the same tpye) ?

Comment: How are you going to handle different types of `language`? It can be string, integer etc

Comment: You are right, I though all of them take a predicate.

Comment: Look at http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/vstudio/bb534501%28v=vs.100%29.aspx GroupBy takes a Func<TSource, TKey> keySelector

Comment: @SergeyBerezovskiy. If the tasks are of type translation, then the language will be the key. Otherwise, the taskorder will be the key.

Comment: @Richard77 nope, it will always be the `language`. But it can have value (and type) of `CultureID` or `TaskOrder`

Comment: Thank all of you. I've fixed the problem and now it's working. I changed the name language to some thing generic like `myKey`.